# Domain "mysitename.com" blacklist request

Tags: feature-request

When using for example/illustration, `example.com` is the canonical domain for this purpose. People are now blocked from submitting `domain.com`, `mydomain.com`, `mysite.com` and so on.

Obviously the list missed this:

```
(my)?site(name)?\.com
```

as it [can be posted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176740). Could it be added to blacklist?